# Is there any way of running VSCode tasks in the *current* integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, settings

By default running tasks inside Visual Studio Code opens a new integrated terminal over the current one, which then asks you to press a key to close it. I would really prefer if the current terminal was used instead, as it gets annoying when many new terminals stack over one another after running several tasks. Is there any way of configuring that? I find it hard to believe no one else dislikes the default behavior but can't seem to find anything online or in the settings.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly I think it should be enough if you set `panel: "shared"` in the `presentation` field of the task json. This will prevent multiple terminals from stacking and they should all try to use the same one.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't so clear. What I meant was, I would like it if the task's command was simply copy-pasted in the existing terminal, rather than opening a new one specifically for tasks (I dislike the task UI in general). The "shared" option is much better than nothing however!

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I don't think/know if this is possible then.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44564) issue is for the same, well, issue. Different solution proposed for the same underlying annoyance.

Answer (score -2):

Go to `.vscode/tasks.json`

change `panel` value to `shared`

```
prefrence : { 
"panel": "shared"
}
```

Comment: What does this mean?